# It is possible to pass a click event from parent Widget to all children Widgets?

Tags: flutter, widget

I'm looking forward to add splash effect to multiple containers when the parents is clicked, would it be that possible?

For example, this Row have several containers that needs to trigger a splash/ripple effect when anywhere in the Row is clicked, how can i achieve this?

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: doSomething,
  child: Row(
    children: [
      InkWell(onTap: reactOnRowClick, child: Container()),
      InkWell(onTap: reactOnRowClick, child: Container()),
      InkWell(onTap: reactOnRowClick, child: Container()),
    ],
  ),
)
```

i've not been able to have the multiple inkwells to work at the same time sadly

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access whole row tap then modify your code like this,

```
  InkWell(
onTap: doSomething,
child: Row(
children: [
InkWell(
onTap: reactOnRowClick,
child: Container()
),
InkWell(
onTap: reactOnRowClick,
child: Container()
)
InkWell(
onTap: reactOnRowClick,
child: Container()
)
])
)
```

Comment: But in this case doSometing on the parent InkWell is not working

Comment: Can you share some code you’ve written on your doSomething so I can do something

Comment: What I need is to add the splash effect for all the items  inside the Row.

So, If i Click on the last item, the 2 previous should show the splash. Sorry, I was working with something similar and mixed information in my previous answer. 

Overall: 
If i click on last item, I need to add the splash effect for the other items if meet requirements (less than X for example)

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Splash effect work on some tap events on widget, it should only work with single widget. If you want perform that on other widgets less than x then put some animations on it

Comment: Yep, this could work, not the best approach but the one we got. Thanks anyway!